# Schema validation failed with the following errors: Data path "/tsconfig" must be array. upgrade from angular 12 to 13

Tags: angular, tsconfig

I have updated my project from angular 12 to angular 13 and when I execute ng test I have following error:

```
Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path "/tsconfig" must be array
```

can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

SO yes I found the problem in out angular.json test:tsconfig needs to be an array not a string so instead :

```
    "test": {
      "builder": "@angular-builders/jest:run",
      "options": {
        "detectOpenHandles": true,
        "coverage": true,
        "tsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json"
      }
    },
```

do this:

```
"test": {
  "builder": "@angular-builders/jest:run",
  "options": {
    "detectOpenHandles": true,
    "coverage": true,
    "tsconfig": ["tsconfig.spec.json"] // <-notice the array
  }
}
```